# Lyx - screen font of accent decoration too small

Tags: fonts, lyx

I use Times New Roman for screen font on Windows 10 and a 4k monitor. Unfortunately, the accent fonts in the math, e.g., \hat, \tilde, are too small and not visible enough. It is quite inconvenient for me.

Even if I change the font family, the accent fonts do not change at all.

And I don't want to turn on the instant preview because the text flashes all the time.

Is it possible to replace only the accent fonts by something else?

Mabye it is a problem caused by the 4k monitor?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed in LyX 3.4.alpha3.

Answer (score 0):

I now guess it is a problem caused by the 4k monitor. I right-click lyx.exe and select Properties-Compatibility-Modify high DPI setting-High DPI Scaling Override, Check Override high DPI scalling behavior, Scaling performed by System. Then the tilde and hat behave as expected, but the text becomes blurry.

So it is best the problem can be solved by Lyx itself. And I open a new ticket on Lyx.org: [screen font of accent decoration too small](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11875)